# displaying a dialable phone number withing the text for a UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, ios4

is there a way that part of the text that is being displayed in an iphone UIAlertView will be a phone number that when clicked will be dialed?
maybe using tel: somehow ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like to implement the dataDetectorType in your message text there is no native way to do it.
The only way is to subclass the UIAlertView and customize the init method like this :

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title message:(NSString *)message delegate:(id)delegate cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ... {
    self = [super initWithTitle:title message:nil delegate:delegate cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle otherButtonTitles:otherButtonTitles, nil];
    if (self) {
        CGRect alertFrame = [self frame];

        UITextView myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(alertFrame.origin.x + 10, alertFrame.origin.y + 44, 200, 44)];
        [myTextView setEditable:NO];
        [myTextView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [myTextView setDataDetectorTypes:UIDataDetectorTypeAll];
        [myTextView setText:@"http://www.apple.com"]; // Use your original message string from init

        [self addSubview:myTextView];
        [myTextView release]
    }
    return self;
}
```

I tested it right now and it works but you need to spend a little bit to make it presentable :P

Maybe using the way posted by Jhaliya is quickly and more clean.

Comment: This looks like what I was looking for. but I will probably need some more help with this to make it work for me. where did you get the 44 and 200 from? your code adds another UITextView to the UIAlertView, right? cant I use the one already inside and call setDataDetectorTypes on it somehow ?

Comment: All the static values I used to setup the frame are arbitrary and you can raplace it to fit with your custom view.
My code do exactly what you said. Unfortunately Apple doesn't provide us the code for any class so I suppose an UIAlertView is composed by an UIView within UILabel for title and UILabel for message plus some UIButtons.
Admitting you could access to this UILabel, but you can't, this class doesn't have support for setDataDetectorTypes. So I thought to draw a simple UITextView on top of message label and use it to display the message. You need to customized it to make it presentable

Answer (score 0):

Yes, This is possible by setting the **delegate** ( [UIAlertViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertViewDelegate_Protocol/UIAlertViewDelegate/UIAlertViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007548) ) of your [UIAlertView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html). Read the **message** and **title** from your **UIAlertView** by using below properties.

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *message
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSString *title
```

---

You need to implement the delegte method in order to get the info for which button pressed.

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
```

you could also follow [link](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/2982-2-button-uialertview-button-pressed.html) for getting pressed button index and  dial an Phone number by Using **tel:** .

---

So, your code could be something like below .

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    //Access `title` and `message` of your **UIAlertView**
    NSString* alertTitle = alertView.title;
    NSString* alertMessage = alertView.message;
    // Formatted the phone number and assign it to a string.
    NSString* myFormattedPhNumber = /*Use StringWithFormat function of NSString */;
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myFormattedPhNumber];
    }
}
```

Comment: just to clarify, If I am reading this properly, then this is working by having a button that does the dialing. this is not what I was asking about. "_is there a way that **part of the text** that ..._"